Difficulty to remove burner unit hot water heater
I have an older hot water heater. It works great but just recently the pilot light won't stay lit. I suspect the thermocouple. I have disconnected everything gas control valve, however, I can't seem to figure out how to remove the protective door/shroud that covers the access to the burner area. I can't find any screws that attach it. There is a thin metal wire handle/latch that was screwed in place. I have removed the screw and tried moving it to see if it "releases" the door but no such luck. It definitely "feels" like it is held in place in the middle somewhere. The top and bottoms are fairly easy to move.  I just don't want to break anything so any advice would be helpful thanks!


if you are talking about removing the burner assembly you often have to lift up and then out.

@FreshCodemonger No the burner unit seems to be free to move. The outside metal box is stuck and no obvious screws are attaching it to the heater.
